# ROOT TTree: Reading from nested branch structure

Tags: c++, tree, root-framework

I am trying to read a branch from a nested branch structure in a ROOT TTree. I can quite easily scan the values, but I can not read them using `tree->GetEntry()`.

The branches are set up like `event.Branch.DataBranch`,
where event is `TDataType = kNoType_t`, Branch is `TDataType = kInt_t` and DataBranch is `TDataType = kDouble_t`. Here is the code I have

```
#include <TFile.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void treeread(){

  TFile *f = new TFile("Data.root");
  TTree* tree = (TTree*)f->Get("TheTree");
  //tree->SetMakeClass(1);

  Double_t Data1;
  Int_t topBranch;

  tree->SetBranchStatus("*",0);
  tree->SetBranchStatus("event.Branch",1);
  tree->SetBranchStatus("event.Branch.DataBranch",1);

  tree->Scan("event.Branch.DataBranch","","", 3, 0);

  tree->SetBranchAddress("event.Branch",&topBranch);
  tree->SetBranchAddress("event.Branch.DataBranch",&Data1);

  for (int i = 0, N = tree->GetEntries(); i < 3; ++i) {
    tree->GetEntry(i);
    cout<<"Data1 = "<<Data1<<endl;
  }
}
```

With the following output when run

```
root [0] .L SimpleTreeRead.C 
root [1] treeread()
***********************************
*    Row   * Instance * event.Bra *
***********************************
*        0 *        0 * 5.1277329 *
*        1 *        0 * 4.4813465 *
*        2 *        0 * 4.3048654 *
***********************************
Data1 = 0
Data1 = 0
Data1 = 0
```

I do not know how to set the branch address for the event branch as it is of type kNoType_t. I suspect this may be the issue, but am clueless on how to resolve it. Also `tree->SetMakeClass(1)` simply results in segmentation faults when used. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here or know what could be going on? Any clues would be much appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: What happens if you remove `tree->SetBranchStatus("*",0);` ?

Comment: What happens if you do `TLeaf * leaf tree->FindLeaf("event.Branch.DataBranch");` outside the loop and invoke `Data1 = leaf->GetValue()` inside?